Batch download files from a shared onedrive folder
I'm attempting to batch download a large number of files from a shared OneDrive (for Business) folder, but I'm having trouble getting the script below to work. It doesn't seem to be locating the folder correctly.
This shared folder contains a lot amount of files, and im hoping to avoid downloading them manually from the web interface, which will take several hours.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
# Parameters
$OneDriveSharedFolderURL = "https://domain-my.sharepoint.com/personal/shared_username_domain_com/SharedFolderName" 

$DownloadPath = "C:\Temp\SharedFolder"

Try {
    # Connect to OneDrive
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $OneDriveSharedFolderURL -UseWebLogin
    
    # Get the shared folder
    $sharedFolder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $OneDriveSharedFolderURL
    
    if ($null -eq $sharedFolder) {
        Write-Host "Shared folder not found." -ForegroundColor Red
        return
    }

    # Get all items from the shared folder
    $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -Folder $sharedFolder -PageSize 500

    # Process subfolders (if any)
    $SubFolders = $ListItems | Where-Object { $_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder" }
    $SubFolders | ForEach-Object {
        $LocalFolder = Join-Path $DownloadPath ($_.FieldValues.FileRef.Substring($sharedFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.Length))
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $LocalFolder)) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $LocalFolder | Out-Null
        }
        Write-Host "Ensured Folder '$LocalFolder'" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }

    # Get all files from the folder
    $FilesColl = $ListItems | Where-Object { $_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File" }

    # Download each file
    $FilesColl | ForEach-Object {
        $FileRelativePath = $_.FieldValues.FileRef.Substring($sharedFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.Length)
        $FileDownloadPath = Join-Path $DownloadPath $FileRelativePath
        $FileFolder = Split-Path $FileDownloadPath -Parent
        
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $FileFolder)) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $FileFolder | Out-Null
        }

        Get-PnPFile -Url $_.FieldValues.FileRef -Path $FileFolder -Filename $_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef -AsFile -Force
        Write-Host "Downloaded File '$($_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef)'" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
Catch {
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}



So according to the docs, the -UseWebLogin uses legacy authentication methods, and doesn't doesn't allow the use of parts of the module. It's also commonly blocked because it doesn't use modern auth. Using the -Interactive switch uses modern auth and enables those other features. I'd start there. It also says it requires running the Register-PnPManagementShellAccess before connecting with the -Interactive switch, so make sure that's done as well.
You're also using a folder path to login to the tenant, which goes against what the docs show, so let's break that out, too. As for the Get-PnPFolder command, it also doesn't use the full URL, it's a relative path using the currently authenticated tenant.
# Parameters
$tenantUrl = "domain-my.sharepoint.com"

$oneDriveFolderPath = "/personal/shared_username_domain_com/SharedFolderName"

# Split into pieces to make building a path easier
$DownloadPath = "C:\Temp\SharedFolder".Split('\')

Try {
    # Connect to OneDrive
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $tenantUrl -Interactive
    
    # Get the shared folder
    $sharedFolder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $oneDriveFolderPath
    
    if ($null -eq $sharedFolder) {
        Write-Host "Shared folder not found." -ForegroundColor Red
        return
    }

    # Get all items from the shared folder
    $AllItems= $sharedFolder | Get-PnPFolderItem -Recursive

    # Create folders
    $AllItems | Where-Object {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder"} | ForEach-Object {
        $folderPath = ($DownloadPath + $_.ServerRelativeUrl.Split("/")) -join '\'
        if(!(Test-Path $folderPath)){
            # If the folder isn't there, create it, and create any folders that don't exist up to this folder
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $folderPath -Force | Out-Null
        }
    }
    
    # Download each file
    $AllItems | Where-Object {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"} | ForEach-Object {
        $fileName = $_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
        
        # Build the path to download the file to
        $filePath = ($DownloadPath + ($_.FieldValues.FileRef.Split('/') | Where-Object {$_ -ne $fileName})) -join '\'
        try{
            Get-PnPFile -Url $_.FieldValues.FileRef -Path $filePath -FileName $fileName -AsFile
            Write-Host "Downloaded File '$($fileName)'" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        
    }
}
    

